# gnuplot unable to run in XCode 4.3.1

Tags: xcode, gnuplot

Im trying to get gnuplot up running for C++ environment in XCode.

Im using following tutorial to archieve my result:
http://www.calozgroup.org/Shulabh/MediaWikiS/index.php5?title=Gnuplot_in_C%2B%2B_using_XCode

- I have created the `libgnuplot.a` and imported this along with the `gnuplot_i.h` into my project.
- Copied `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot` into `/usr/local/bin`
- I have created the `~/MacOSX/environment.plist` file with following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DT$
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
          <key>GNUTERM</key>
          <string>aqua</string>
          <key>PATH</key>
          <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin</string>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

The error occurs when compiling following sample code:

```
char myStr[] = "text";
char myEqu[] = "sin(x)";

gnuplot_ctrl *h;
h = gnuplot_init();
gnuplot_plot_equation(h, myEqu, myStr);
gnuplot_close(h);
```

Error:

```
cannot find gnuplot in your PATH(lldb)
```

Furthermore i was getting following compiler warnings:

`Conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated`

```
gnuplot_setstyle(handle, "lines");
```

I tried to modify these to:

```
char line_string[] = "lines";
gnuplot_setstyle(handle, line_string);
```

Comment: can you open gnuplot from the terminal?  If so, what does the output of `which gnuplot` yield?

Comment: `gnuplot` works flawless from terminal, i have been using it this way. `which gnuplot` gives `/opt/local/bin/gnuplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled gnuplot and it suddenly worked.

Comment: If that is a good enough answer for you, then you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: I will as soon as 22hours has passed to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on these things, but try adding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DT$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>GNUTERM</key>
        <string>aqua</string>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin</string> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

(added **/opt/local/bin** to PATH)

Comment: Unfortunately same result. Worth the shot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. gnuplot worked from the terminal, but not from c++.
The c++ code called getenv("PATH") and searched for "gnuplot" throwing an exception when it could not be found. After copying /opt/local/bin/gnuplot into /usr/local/bin, it didn't work as in your case.
But then I decided to also copy it into /usr/bin and this seems to work.

labjunky